# Cancel backButton click in my navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a custom navigationController :

```
#import "customNavigationController.h"
#import "StartViewController.h"
#import "EtapeViewController.h"

@implementation customNavigationController

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Accueil du guide, on cache le navigationBar
    if([self.viewControllers count] == 2){
        self.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }
    // Si on est pas à l'accueil, on fait l'action normal sur le backBarButton
    else {
        // Si on est dans une étape, le backButton va servir à reculer dans les étapes, et non reculer vers le workflow
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[self.viewControllers count] - 1] class]);
        if ([className isEqualToString:@"EtapeViewController"]) {
            EtapeViewController *etape = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[self.viewControllers count] - 1];
            if (etape.show_previous_button) {
                [etape previousEtape:nil];
                return FALSE;
            }
            return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
        }
        else {
            return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

In some case, I want to cancel the click event of the backButton (on the line that reads "return FALSE"), but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in place of `return FALSE`, you can do:

```
return nil;
```

or

```
return [self topViewController];
```

Either should have the right side effect.

That being said, be careful with your UI design here.  Make sure the user knowns why the back button doesn't work somehow.

Comment: Both don't work as expected. The view doesn't change to the previous view in the stack (as expected), but the navigation bar slide to the left (as if it would go back to the previous view in the stack).

Comment: Try implementing `- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item` and returning NO for the specified case.

Comment: In general though, this entire scheme you set up seems very fragile.  The Back button behavior isn't supposed to be modified.  I would consider using regular buttons like "Done", "Save" and "Cancel" if you need specific custom behavior...

Comment: @amattn Thanks! returning NO works as expected, but returning YES is weird, the view doesn't pop (or slides to the left), only the navigationBar slide to the left... any idea?

Comment: I found it, return NO if you want to cancel the event, but don't return YES if you want the event to fire, use this instead : return [super navigationBar:navigationBar shouldPopItem:item];

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would make the Back button ignore taps? It seems like this would confuse users and the App Store team would consider this a bug. Perhaps you could you post a screenshot?

It would probably be better to redesign your interface and consider 1) using toolbar buttons for navigation (like Mobile Safari) or 2) fully support UINavigation based views rather than working around it.

---

Update: It sounds like you're going to perform a different action, like displaying a confirmation? I don't know of any *official* ways to do what you want, since the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods just notify you about transitions, they don't let you cancel/modify them. (And if the transition is animated then playing with the navigation controller's view stack probably won't help.)

So you could always float a transparent (or almost transparent) window over the back button and intercept taps that way. Here's some sample bar that does something similar with the status bar:

https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay

Comment: In fact, what I want to do is to call another function, and then cancel the backButton event. Disabling the button wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you disable the back button in the situations that you don't want the user to tap it?

Comment: In fact, what I want to do is to call another function, and then cancel the backButton event. Disabling the button wouldn't work.